# Folium Search Plugin Does Search Popup Text

Tags: python-3.x, search, folium

I have got the Folium search box plugin working for Code 2 however, as I want to have circle markers instead and not have to zoom in to see grouped markers, Code 1 is what I'm stuck trying to fix. The search box doesn't seem to want to search for the Site ID or Postcode (says 'location not found') unlike in Code 2 which works perfectly. Any help is appreciated

**CODE 1**

```
import folium
from folium.plugins import Search
import pandas as pd
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from datetime import datetime

excel_file_path = r'test.xlsx'

columns_to_read = ['Status', 'Updates', 'Site ID', 'Site Name', 'Address 1', 'Postcode', 'Site Tier Classification', 'Circuit Handover Date']
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path, sheet_name='Tracker', engine='openpyxl', usecols=columns_to_read)
df['Site ID'] = df['Site ID'].astype(str).str.rstrip('.0')

def get_coordinates(postcode):
    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="postcode_mapper")
    location = geolocator.geocode(postcode)
    return (location.latitude, location.longitude) if location else None

def visualize_locations_with_circle_markers(df, zoom=6):
    center_lat, center_lon = 54.7023545, -3.2765753  

    uk_map = folium.Map([center_lat, center_lon], zoom_start=zoom)

    feature_group = folium.FeatureGroup(name='Locations').add_to(uk_map)

    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        coordinates = get_coordinates(row['Postcode'])

        if coordinates:
            pin_date = row['Circuit Handover Date']
            if pd.isnull(pin_date):
                pin_color = 'grey'
            else:
                if isinstance(pin_date, pd.Timestamp):
                    pin_date = pin_date.date()

                pin_color = 'red' if pin_date > datetime.today().date() else 'green'

            html_table = df.loc[[row.name]].to_html(classes="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed table-responsive", index=False)

            popup_content = f"<b>Site ID:</b> {row['Site ID']}<br><b>Postcode:</b> {row['Postcode']}<br><b>Address:</b> {row['Address 1']}<br>{html_table}"

            folium.CircleMarker(
                location=coordinates,
                radius=5,
                color=pin_color,
                fill=True,
                fill_color=pin_color,
                fill_opacity=1.0,
                popup=folium.Popup(popup_content, max_width=800),
                siteIDsearch=row['Site ID'],  
                postcodesearch=row['Postcode']  
            ).add_to(feature_group)

    uk_map.add_child(feature_group)

    servicesearch = Search(
        layer=feature_group,
        search_label="siteIDsearch", 
        placeholder='Search for a Site ID',
        collapsed=False,
    ).add_to(uk_map)

    postcodesearch = Search(
        layer=feature_group,
        search_label="postcodesearch",  
        placeholder='Search for a Postcode',
        collapsed=False,
    ).add_to(uk_map)

    return uk_map

visualize_locations_with_circle_markers(df).save("map_with_search_and_circles.html")
print("Map saved as HTML.")
```

## **vs**

**CODE 2**

```
import folium
from folium.plugins import MarkerCluster, Search
import pandas as pd
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from datetime import datetime

excel_file_path = r'test.xlsx'

columns_to_read = ['Status', 'Updates', 'Site ID', 'Site Name', 'Address 1', 'Postcode', 'Site Tier Classification', 'Circuit Handover Date']
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path, sheet_name='Tracker', engine='openpyxl', usecols=columns_to_read)
df['Site ID'] = df['Site ID'].astype(str).str.rstrip('.0')

def get_coordinates(postcode):
    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="postcode_mapper")
    location = geolocator.geocode(postcode)
    return (location.latitude, location.longitude) if location else None

def visualize_locations_with_cluster_markers(df, zoom=6):
    center_lat, center_lon = 54.7023545, -3.2765753  

    uk_map = folium.Map([center_lat, center_lon], zoom_start=zoom)

    marker_cluster = MarkerCluster(name='Locations').add_to(uk_map)

    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        coordinates = get_coordinates(row['Postcode'])

        if coordinates:
            pin_date = row['Circuit Handover Date']
            if pd.isnull(pin_date):
                pin_color = 'grey'
            else:
                if isinstance(pin_date, pd.Timestamp):
                    pin_date = pin_date.date()

                pin_color = 'red' if pin_date > datetime.today().date() else 'green'

            html_table = df.loc[[row.name]].to_html(classes="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed table-responsive", index=False)

            popup_content = f"<b>Site ID:</b> {row['Site ID']}<br><b>Postcode:</b> {row['Postcode']}<br><b>Address:</b> {row['Address 1']}<br>{html_table}"

            folium.Marker(
                location=coordinates,
                icon=folium.Icon(color=pin_color),
                popup=folium.Popup(popup_content, max_width=800),
                siteIDsearch=row['Site ID'],  
                postcodesearch=row['Postcode']  
            ).add_to(marker_cluster)

    uk_map.add_child(marker_cluster)

    servicesearch = Search(
        layer=marker_cluster,
        search_label="siteIDsearch",  
        placeholder='Search for a Site ID',
        collapsed=False,
    ).add_to(uk_map)

    postcodesearch = Search(
        layer=marker_cluster,
        search_label="postcodesearch", 
        placeholder='Search for a Postcode',
        collapsed=False,
    ).add_to(uk_map)

    return uk_map

visualize_locations_with_cluster_markers(df).save("map_with_search_and_cluster.html")
print("Map saved as HTML.")
```

How do I get code 1 to search for Site ID and Postcode which seems to work in code 2 but need it to work in code 1 instead.